# Docker Toolbox - Slow mysql connection only by browser

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker, docker-compose

i have docker toolbox for windows home and I have a file that queries the database, but the speed detected by chrome to see the results is slow. 
If I run a query from the php storm terminal it is immediate. I would like to know if there is a solution to this slowdown. 
The file I am running to test is just an empty file with only the code for the query, for try the problem. 
I need to test things quickly. I don't know what i do to do to solve the problem.
Thank you

Comment: show us your docker setup

Comment: "docker info"? Server Version: 18.06.1-ce - Kernel Version: 4.9.93-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 18.06.1-ce (TCL 8.2.1); 
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 995.6MiB
Name: default. I have the container portainerw with mysql 5.7 and php 7.1

Comment: I meant moree like your DockerFile or docker-compose.yml

Comment: sorry - 
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=psw
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=name
    - MYSQL_USER=nameuser
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=psw
  volumes:
  #    - ./etc/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    - ./etc/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    - ./varlog/mysql:/var/log/mysql/
    - ./data/dumpdb.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dumpdb.sql  . I can not post everything(limit characters), the other code is of php and portainer. Everything works but the problem is the difference in the response of a query from phpstorm and browser.